# Rails Versions 3.1.0 to 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently developing on my Windows 7 machine with railsinstaller and i have rails 3.1.0.

However my hosting ISP is running Rails 2.3.14.

What would be the best solution around this down grade my machine or is there another way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i'd seriously consider switching your hosting provider

Comment: I thought of that but not sure who is the best that provides 3.1.0

Comment: I don't have windos experience. but I believe, using `gem uninstall rails -v 3.1.0` and `gem install rails -v 2.3.14`

Comment: Heroku is free for a single dyno - AWS on a micro instance is $18 p/m. For a low volume app both should be capable.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing exactly the same situation.
The solution (especially for local development) was Ruby Version Manager (RVM) and Bundler.

LINKS:

http://beginrescueend.com/

http://gembundler.com/rails23.html